# Record Kinematic Data in Oculus Rift

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

Trying to record kinematic data of hand movement with Oculus rift rather than a motion capture camera. Save the positional data in the x,y,z coordinate planes of the hand and give them some kind of print out or upload to MATLAB file.

Coding in Unity using visual studio.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what‘s your problem exactly ?

Comment: I have experimented with setting float values for (x,y,z) then setting the variables in the code equal to their respective transform.position and then trying to establish a print statement or return type.